# Can anyone explain the output printf("%0 %x",a);?

Tags: c

This code is making me so confused. I can't understand what `%0` is doing inside `printf`!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 100;
    printf("%0 %x", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
%x
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour: The `printf` function doesn't know what t do with `%0` so, after that, all bets are off.

Comment: Hmm. Looking for a duplicate but none seem forthcoming ...

Comment: MSVC generates two warnings for that line. Don't ignore them.

Comment: if you compile with flags `-Wall` and `-Werror`, (at least on `gcc`) you will get an error: `error: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Werror=format=] 6 |     printf("%0 %x",a);`

Comment: Please either delete the unneeded C++ code or retag to C++.

Comment: `Can anyone explain` What `printf` implementation are you using? What platform are you on? Windows? Linux? Alpine Linux? Or other?

Comment: @S.B: You can accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark below its score.

Comment: I was waiting for any other input on this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%0 %x` has an invalid `printf` conversion specification:

- the `0` is a flag specifying that the number representation should be padded with initial zeroes to the specified width (which is not specified here)
- the   is a flag specifying that the signed conversion should be prefixed with a space if positive in the same place as a `-` for negative numbers.
- the second `%` is the conversion specifier, so the initial part is just a variation of `%%` with 2 extra flags and thus should cause a `%` character to be output, but the C Standard specifies in **7.21.6.20 the `fprintf` function** that

  > `%`: A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification shall be `%%`.

  Hence `%0 %` is an invalid conversion specification as `%` does not accept flags.

Most libraries will just output `%x`, ie: `%` for `%0 %` and `x` for the trailing `x`, ignoring the `a` argument, and this is what you get on your system, but the behavior is actually undefined, so nothing can be assumed.

Conversely, `printf("|%0 5d|", 100);` will output `| 0100|` but the space is ignored for the `x` conversion which is unsigned so `printf("|%0 5x|", 100);` will output `|00064|`.

Comment: Interesting that "The complete conversion specification shall be %%" is also in C99, C89.  UB for some time now.